# Symfony Rest Controller Limiting serialization depth

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I have entity bit and relation ManyToMany developer, for developer I use * @Groups({"for_project"}) and when I use this anotation, in response not see fields developer, I look documentation and see * @MaxDepth(2) and use this but still have null. Why ?

```
 {
"0": {
"id": 501,
"created": "2015-11-27T12:25:11+0200",
"developer_id": {},
"rate": 4,
"comment": "fsefsf"
},
"1": {
"id": 502,
"created": "2015-11-27T12:25:46+0200",
"developer_id": {},
"rate": 3,
"comment": "feasf"
}
}

class Bit
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @Expose()
 * @Groups({"for_project"})
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var datetime $created
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Expose()
 * @Groups({"for_project"})
 */
private $created;

/**
 * @var datetime $updated
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Groups({"for_project"})
 */
private $updated;

/**
 * @var \Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developer
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Developer")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="developer_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     * })
     * @Expose()
     * @Groups({"for_project"})
     * @MaxDepth(2)
     */
    private $developerId;


class BitController extends FOSRestController
...anotaion block 
public function getBitByProjectAction($id, $token)
{
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Users')->findOneBySecuritytoken($token);

    if (!empty($user) || $security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') ) {
        $bits = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
            ->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Bit')
            ->findBitByProject($id, $token);
        if (!$bits) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }
        return View::create()
            ->setStatusCode(200)
            ->setData($bits)
            ->setSerializationContext(
                SerializationContext::create()
                    ->enableMaxDepthChecks()
                    ->setGroups(array("for_project"))
            );
```

**SOLVED**
I understand, need add * @Groups({"for_project"}) for fields entity developer
but when I deleted @MaxDepth I still have fields entity developer, why need @MaxDepth ? 
I understand, when use without @MaxDept, we have maximum depth for relation fields, Example I have entity Bit, bit have Developer and developer have User, if I want visible fields entity User I need add @MaxDept(3) for field developer in entity Bit

Comment: What you got when removing @MaxDepth annotation? Also can you please show imported class?

Comment: when I deleted @MaxDepth I have still empty developer, when I deleted * @Groups({"for_project"}) I have information about developer. I need add * @Groups({"for_project"}) for fields entity developer ?

Comment: I understand I need add  * @Groups({"for_project"}) for fileds developer

Comment: @shuba.ivan post your solution as an answer ;)

Comment: good to know you solved it

Answer (score 2):

when use without @MaxDept, we have maximum depth for relation fields, Example I have entity Bit, bit have Developer and developer have User, if I want visible fields entity User I need add @MaxDept(3) for field developer in entity Bit
in action:

```
            return View::create()
            ->setStatusCode(200)
            ->setData($bits)
            ->setSerializationContext(
                SerializationContext::create()
                    ->enableMaxDepthChecks()
                    ->setGroups(array("for_project"))
            );
```

and in response

```
[
{
"id": 501,
"created": "2015-11-30T17:49:19+0200",
"developer_id": {
  "id": 201,
  "rate": 0,
  "user": [
    {
      "first_name": "Ivan",
      "last_name": "Shuba"
    }
  ]
},
"rate": 4,
"comment": "fsefse"
 }
]
```

and Entity

```
class Bit
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @Expose()
 * @Groups({"for_project"})
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var datetime $created
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Expose()
 * @Groups({"for_project"})
 */
private $created;

/**
 * @var datetime $updated
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Groups({"for_project"})
 */
private $updated;

/**
 * @var \Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developer
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Developer")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="developer_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     * })
     * @Expose()
     * @Groups({"for_project"})
     * @MaxDepth(3)
     */
    private $developerId;

class Developer
{
    /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Users", mappedBy="developer",  cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @Expose()
 * @Groups({"for_project"})
 */
protected $user;

class Users implements UserInterface
{
    /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Expose()
 * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=255)
 * @Groups({"for_project"})
 */
protected $firstName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 * @Expose()
 * @Groups({"for_project"})
 */
protected $lastName;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using fos rest version: 2* and JMS serializer version: 3*

```
return $this->view($data)->setContext((new Context())->enableMaxDepth());
```